# We take $1,2,\dots,n^{2}$ to form an $n\times n$ matrix, then what is the range of rank of the set of matrices that are formed in this way?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with entries $1, 2, \dots, n^2$ (without repeating), e.g., when $n=2$,

$$ A \in \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1& 2\\ 3&4 \end{bmatrix}, \ \ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}, \dots \right\} $$

Let $r(A)$ denote the rank of $A$. What are the possible values of $r(A)$?

Clearly, $r(A) \in \{ 1, 2, \dots, n\}$ and I have constructed rank-$2$ and rank-$n$ matrices. I guess $r(A)$ can be any natural number from $2$ to $n$, but I don't know how to construct matrix with rank $k$, where $2<k<n$.

Comment: Have you attempted a computer simulation shuffling in all possible ways numbers $1,2, ... n^2$ (for low values of $n$ of course) ?

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that for any $2 < k \leq n$, the following procedure results in a matrix containing entries $1,2,\dots,n^2$ has rank $k$. I've checked it for all $3 \leq n \leq 20$ and $2 < k \leq n$; I hope to add a proof once I have the time.

1. Begin with the rank-2 matrix
   $$
   A_0 = \pmatrix{
   1 & 2 & \cdots & n\\
   n+1 & n+2 & \cdots & 2n\\
   \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
   n^2 - n + 1 & n^2 - n + 2 & \cdots & n^2}
   $$
2. For each $i = 1,\dots,k-2$, swap the entries $A_{i,i}$ and $A_{i,i+1}.$

For example, with $n = 6$ and $k = 4$ we get the matrix
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}\color{red}2 & \color{red}1 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
7 & \color{red}9 & \color{red}8 & 10 & 11 & 12\\13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18\\19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24\\25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30\\31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36\end{pmatrix},
$$
which indeed has rank $4$.

---

So far, I am able to show that the statement holds for $2<k<n$, but the case of $k=n$ is surprisingly tricky.

*Attempted proof:* We can write the rank-2 matrix $A_0$ as the following product:
$$
A_0 = 
\pmatrix{
1&1&\cdots & 1\\
0&n&\cdots & n^2-n}^T
\pmatrix{
1&2&\cdots&n\\
1&1&\cdots&1}
$$
The modified matrix can be written as
$$
A = 
{\underbrace{\pmatrix{
1&1&\cdots & 1\\
0&n&\cdots & n^2-n\\
1&0&\cdots & 0\\
0&1&\ddots\\
&&\ddots}}_B}^T
\underbrace{
\pmatrix{
1&2&\cdots&n\\
1&1&\cdots&1\\
1&-1&0&\cdots\\
&1&-1&\ddots\\
&&\ddots&\ddots}
}_C
$$
Where both matrices in the product ($B$ and $C$) $k$ rows. It suffices to show that $B$ and $C$ have rank $k$.

The matrix $B$ can be written in the block-matrix form
$$
B = \pmatrix{B_{11} & B_{12}\\I_{k-2} & 0}.
$$
We can apply block-row operations to get
$$
B \leadsto \pmatrix{0 & B_{12}\\I_{k-2} & 0} \leadsto 
\pmatrix{I_{k-2} & 0\\ 0 & B_{12}}.
$$
Thus, the rank of $B$ is equal to $(k-2) + \operatorname{rank}(B_{12})$, where
$$
B_{12} = \pmatrix{
1&1&\cdots & 1\\
(k-2)n & (k-1)n & \cdots & (n-1)n}
$$
Now, we need only remark that $B_{12}$ has linearly independent rows and therefore has rank $2$.

Similarly, $C$ can be written as
$$
C = \pmatrix{C_{11} & C_{12}\\ U & C_{22}},
$$
where $U$ is upper-triangular and invertible. We can apply block-row operations to get
$$
\pmatrix{C_{11} & C_{12}\\ U & C_{22}} \leadsto
\pmatrix{0 & C_{12} - C_{11}U^{-1}C_{22}\\ U & C_{22}},
$$
so it suffices to show that $C_{12} - C_{11}U^{-1}C_{22}$ has rank 2. We have
$$
U^{-1} = \pmatrix{
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
0 & 1 & \ddots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 1\\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 1}, \quad 
C_{11} = 
\pmatrix{
1&2&\cdots&k-2\\
1&1&\cdots&1},
\\C_{12} = 
\pmatrix{
k-1 & k & \cdots & n\\
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1
}, \quad C_{22} = \pmatrix{&&&\\ \\ -1}.
$$
Notably, $C_{22}$ has all zero entries except for in its first column. Thus, the same is true for the product $C_{11}U^{-1}C_{22}$. Thus, all columns of $C_{12} - C_{11}U^{-1}C_{22}$ except the first are equal to that of $C_{12}$. Thus, to show that $C_{12} - C_{11}U^{-1}C_{22}$ has linearly independent rows, it suffices to show that the matrix attained by removing the first column of $C_{12} - C_{11}U^{-1}C_{22}$ has independent rows, which is to say that the matrix attained by removing the first column of $C_{12}$ has linearly independent columns. That is, it suffices to note that the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{
k & \cdots & n\\
1 & \cdots & 1}
$$
has independent columns, which is indeed true for $k < n$.